# mysql constraint int(10) referencing int(11)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a database with foreign key constraint where an int(10) is referencing an int(11). I also have int(11) reference int(10).

Their aren't any errors. Will this ever cause problems in the future? (Besides the problem of running out of space for an integer)

I had a kind of related problem when trying to change the column size for a varchar:

[mysql 5.6 foreign key constraint error; didn't occur in 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015844/mysql-5-6-foreign-key-constraint-error-didnt-occur-in-5-5)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632403 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562322

Comment: And some of my previous answers on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573451 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's no problem.  The INT(10) and INT(11) are exactly the same data type (32-bit signed integer) with respect to storage and range of values. The integer argument is only a hint for display.

Also varchar columns of different lengths are okay to use in foreign key relationships. Obviously these *do* have a different range of values they permit. But it's okay.

Say for example the parent table has a shorter VARCHAR(10) and the child has VARCHAR(20). The child still can't use a string longer than 10 characters, because it must match a string in the parent table, and there simply won't be any longer than 10 characters.

It works in reverse too; if the parent has VARCHAR(20) and the child has VARCHAR(10). The child won't be able to reference longer strings in the parent, but it's never mandatory that the child table reference *every* value in the parent table, only those it can reference.

Based on this reasoning, you might think that the same logic would apply to integers, so a SMALLINT should be able to reference a BIGINT. But MySQL doesn't permit this.